# Placeholder syntax for Node mysql “ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE” clause with multiple rows and columns update

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am struggling to find the correct syntax when using placeholders with an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause when multiple rows and columns need to be updated.

The example below is how I would do a simple Insert command for multiple rows. The "?" placeholder is replaced by the array values.

But how would I do it if I want to use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE? The various examples I have found seem to say that we have to explicitly show each key=value pair, which precludes the possibility of using the "?" placeholder.

```
let twoDimensionArray = [keycol, colA, colB, colC, colD]
// iterate to add more rows.

let fullQuery = "INSERT INTO myTable (keycol, colA, colB, colC, colD) VALUES ?"

con.query(fullQuery,[twoDimensionArray], function(err, result) {
  //do stuff
});
```

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-or-update-on-duplicate-key-update/

Comment: Thank you. But I am not sure that this tutorial covers my use case. According to the tutorial, we must specify each column-value-pair to be updated explicitly, which could be tedious to maintain in situations with many dozens of columns.
I am hoping to find the way to do it using a "?" placehoders, like in the above example.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by joining the array in a single string and concatenating directly in the query. Note that I also had column names with spaces so I needed to encase them in back quotes by using the map funtion.

The end result is as follows:

```
let twoDimensionArray = [keycol, colA, colB, colC, colD, colname with spaces]
// iterate to add more rows.

let fullQuery = "INSERT INTO myTable (" + twoDimensionArray.map(colName => '`'+colName+'`').join(',') + ") VALUES ?"

con.query(fullQuery,[twoDimensionArray], function(err, result) {
  //do stuff
});
```